# My sdcard is showing up in storage, but I can't place apps on it. 0

Tags: external-sd, tablet

My sdcard is mounted, but I can't store apps to it. My HP tablet run Android 4.2.2.

This is a new Sdcard.

Comment: Did your old SD card work? Have you tried a different new SD card? What does "can't store apps to it mean"? How have you determined that you can't store apps to it and what errors, if any, are you receiving?

Comment: Should I assume that "Move to SD card" is either not available or greyed out under Settings ->Apps of any app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a rooted phone with a proper Android ROM, you will not be able to place all apps in the SD card. Specific apps allow you to do so, but others, like Whatsapp, don't even allow to place media on the external storage. That's a shame.

Starting with (non-rooted) standard Android 4.2.2 ROMs, apps no longer can have full access to SD card.